# After Encodeing json i have and extra whitespace, how can i remove that?

Tags: php, json

i have the following array whitch i want to encode to jSon:

```
$output = array("success" =>0,"msg" => "The e-mail address is already in use");
```

I am useing the following method to encode:

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

As a result I get back the following string:

```
{"success":0,"msg":"The e-mail address is already in use"}﻿
```

I seems perfectly okey but I have an extra whitespace at the end witch prevent me for useing the jSon string any further. Can anyone help me how to remove this whitespace from the end?

Comment: after you do `echo json_encode($output);` is there any other output from that script?

Comment: nothing, after this row I just simply close the php tag

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: do you have ending PHP tags such as `?>` if you have any line returns or stuff after the ending tags they get output as well, I personally never use end tags for that very reason.

Comment: see its this `I just simply close the php tag` PHP is just fine without them closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you have some content after an ending PHP tag.  As an example:

```
<?php
    $output = array("success" =>0,"msg" => "The e-mail address is already in use");
    echo json_encode($output);
?>   
\n
```

Now I cant represent a new line in the code block but assume the `\n` is a line return.  Now after the PHP tags it will echo the json, and then after PHP tags it echos any content such as that new line.  You can however just remove the end tag.  This is also true of the open tag and any content there will likewise be output, but that one is much easier to spot if its at the top of the file.

Or at least that's my best guess if you have `{...}\n` as your json output.

It's an extremely easy mistake to make that can be hard to spot.  It may seem strange, but it does happen like this.

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem, I had 2 exta rows after the closing tag

Comment: Yep, yep.. been there done that, got the hat and the t-shirt.  I would just do away with the end tag altogether.  I haven't used them in about 3 years because of that issue, lol